# 502 Bad gateway internal server error lambda serving binary files

Tags: aws-lambda, serverless-framework, binary-data

I'm fetching a file from node-fetch, like this

```
module.exports.somelambdafunction = async (event, context, callback) => {
    const streamData = await fetch(some file url, {
          headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${this.accessToken}`,
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
        });
    const buffer = await streamData.buffer(); 
    response.headers = {
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET, POST',
      'Content-Type': 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document',
      Accept: 'application/octet-stream',
      'Content-disposition': `attachment; filename=${getSpFileAttributes.LinkFilename}`,
    };
    response.body = buffer;
    response.isBase64Encoded = true;
    return response;
}
```

given buffer I also set isBase64Encoded  to be true. I'm using serverless to deploy this thing. However when calling the endpoint I keep getting Internal Server Error. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Did you convert the buffer to Base64? I am pretty sure if you set isBase64Encoded to true the API gateway wants the body to be Base64, so that the gateway convert it to binary.
And try activating CloudWatch logging for the API gateway for better errors: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-logging.html